# Return result of instance method with values()

Tags: django, model

I have a dict and want to add serialized models there

```
dict = {
    'color': 'green',
    'cars': Car.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name'),
    'bikes': Bike.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
}
```

This works, as long as `name` is an actual field. But if I want to use an instance method from the object, `values()` cannot return it:

```
dict = {
    'color': 'green',
    'cars': Car.objects.all().values_list('id', 'get_beautified_name'),
    'bikes': Bike.objects.all().values_list('id', 'get_beautified_name')
}
```

So, what could I do to generate a dict of my objects like `values()` does, just with also calling the results of the instance methods? Do I have to build a serializer for that single purpose? That sounds a bit overstated (and I am still not experienced in that...)

Comment: No, you can not do this. But why not simply use an `Object` instance, so dropping the `values_list`?

Comment: Why not use list comprehension here? Something like:
`[(obj.id, obj.method_name()) for obj in Object.objects.all()]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because I want to serialize it to json, and its one field within a "manually build" dictionary, so I also cant use the serializer for django objects

Comment: @Asara: then you probably better use something that is made to serialize: a *serializer* https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, building a serializer seems to be a bit overstated for my single purpose?! I rephrased my question

Comment: @henriquesalvaro, thanks that works. Unfortunately I did a mistake, because actually I need the fieldnames as well, like values() does and not values_list()